# Can we show that $t\mapsto\operatorname E\left[\int_0^tM_s\:{\rm d}s\right]$ is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space and $(M_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $[0,\infty)$-valued right-continuous process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$g(t):=\operatorname E\left[\int_0^tM_s\:{\rm d}s\right]<\infty\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag1$$ (we assume that $M:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is $(\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B([0,\infty))$-measurable).

Are we able to show that $g$ is differentiable with $$g'(t)=\operatorname E[M_t]\tag2$$ for all $t\ge0$?

Is this an application of [Lebesgue's differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) or [Leibniz' integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) or is there an elementary proof in this particular case?

Comment: Why can't you simply apply Fubini, exchange expectation and the time integral, and then use classical fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @a_student The classical fundamtenal theorem of calculus requires the integrand to be a continuous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we cannot. In the special case when $M_t$ is not random you are asking if the indefinite intergal of any non-negative  right-continuous (locally) integrable function is differentiable. I am sure you can find a counter-example for this.

Comment: If $M$ is not random, then $$g(t)=\int_0^tM_s\:{\rm d}s\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0.$$ So, I think I'm not asking if any nonengative right-continuous locally integrable function is differentiable, but if the integral of such a function is differentiable.

Comment: It is differentiable a.e. but not necessarily everywhere, consider $M$ which jumps from 0 to 1 at the origin.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I forgot to type the indefinite integral but the conclusion is still false.

Comment: So, okay. I guess the "differentiable a.e." result mentioned by @YuvalPeres is the more general fact that if $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $h\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda)$, then $$f(t):=\int_{(-\infty,\:t]}h(t)\:\lambda({\rm d}t)\;\;\;\text{for t}\ge0$$ is differentiable $\lambda$-almost everywhere, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, that is right.

Comment: However, what if we additionally assume that $\lim_{s\to t-}M_s(\omega)$ exists for all $\omega\in\Omega$ and $t\ge0$? Is that sufficient?

Comment: @0xbadf00d No that is not enough. You can find an example with $M_t$ monotone (in which case left and right limits exist at every point).